# How to get list of unique values of 2 fields in one query/table?

Tags: firebird

for ex. I have this query

```
select distinct t1.date1, t2.date2
from t1
join t2 ...
....
where ...
```

and I want to get list of unique values of this 2 dates. How can i perfom this on Firebird 2.5?

I try this

```
with dates as (
select t1.date1 d1, t2.date2 d2
from t1
join t2 ...
....
where ...)
select d1 from dates
union
select d2 from dates
```

but this version will slow perfomance as twice

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
with dates (dt) as (
  select t1.date1 from t1
  where (1=1) --conditions

  union

  select t2.date2 from t2
  where (1=1) --conditions
)

select unique dt
from dates
```